# why am I getting "application not a procedure"?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I am trying to write a procedure that computes f by means of an iteratve process. The function f is defined by the rule that

f(n) = n, if n < 4 and

f(n) = f(n - 1) + 2f(n - 2) + 3f(n - 3) + 4f(n - 4), if n >= 4.

Here is my procedure:

```
(define (f n)
  (define (newF temp n)
    (letrec ((first (- n 1))
             (second (- n 2))
             (third/fourth (- n 3))
             (fifth (- n 4)))
      (define (d)
        ((if (< first 4) (set! temp (+ temp first)) (newF temp first))
         (if (< second 4) (set! temp (+ temp (* second 2))) (newF temp second))
         (if (< third/fourth 4) (set! temp (+ temp (* third/fourth 3) (* third/fourth 4))) (newF temp third/fourth))
         (if (< fifth 4) (set! temp (+ temp (* fifth 4)))(newF temp fifth))))
      (d))
    temp)
  (newF 0 n))
```

Unfortunately, when I ran (f 7), I got this error(which referred to the if statement body):

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...:
   #<void>
   #<void>
   #<void>
```

Anyone know the reason why and how I can fix it?

Comment: You see the two `((` before the if? The `set!` returns void and it tries to apply that as a procedure

Comment: Did you search for that error message before asking this question?  A [google search for `"application: not a procedure" site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22application%3A+not+a+procedure%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) turns up a whole bunch of results, and you'll quickly find that it's in the `((if ....) ...)`.  That first `(if ...)` returns something (that's not a function), and then you try to call it like a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["application: not a procedure" in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/application-not-a-procedure-in-binary-arithmetic-procedures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26079480/13), you're going about it in a totally imperative way (and incorrect, of course, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question), which is not how Scheme likes to work. Here's a functional (but not iterative) way to write the function:

```
(define (f n)
  (if (< n 4)
      n
      (+ (f (- n 1)) (* 2 (f (- n 2))) (* 3 (f (- n 3))) (* 4 (f (- n 4))))))
```

Now, let's see how one might write this iteratively. First, let's see how an iterative Fibonacci function is written:

```
(define (fib n)
  (let loop ((i 0) (a 0) (b 1))
    (if (>= i n)
        a
        (loop (+ i 1) b (+ a b)))))
```

This does the same thing as the following JavaScript:

```
fib = function (n) {
  return (function loop(i, a, b) {
            return i >= n ? a : loop(i + 1, b, a + b);
          })(0, 0, 1);
};
```

Notice how `i`, `a`, and `b` actually get updated. We use tail-recursion to update the values, not by reassignment/mutation (i.e., not using `=` in JS or `set!` in Scheme). I recently wrote an answer about [why tail-recursion is so important in Scheme](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-worry-or-learn-about-Tail-Call-Optimization/answer/Chris-Jester-Young).

So, you would do something similar with your function:

```
(define (f n)
  (let loop ((i 0) (a 0) (b 1) (c 2) (d 3))
    (if (>= i n)
        a
        (loop (+ i 1) b c d (+ d c c b b b a a a a)))))
```

Comment: I never knew one could use let to create a procedure. Interesting

Comment: Indeed! I wrote a post about [named `let`](http://dyscour.se/post/58639636506/named-let), too, which explains how they work behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

The error reported occurs because there are a couple of unnecessary `()` surrounding the expressions inside the `d` helper procedure. You don't have to do that, all the expressions inside a procedure are implicitly inside a `begin`, there's no need to use `()` to indicate that they're all part of a block of code - and besides, when we surround an expression with `()` the interpreter tries to apply the expression as if it were a procedure - hence the `application: not a procedure` error.

Other than that, some comments about style are in order. In Scheme, we try to avoid using `set!`, that's not the idiomatic way to solve a problem in this programming language. Also, you're overwriting some built-in procedures in Racket: `first`, `second` and `fifth` are names already in use, you should not use them for your own variables.