# Iterative tree calculation in scheme

Tags: scheme, iteration, racket

I'm trying to implement a function defined as such:

```
f(n) = n if n < 4
f(n) = f(n - 1) + 2f(n - 2) + 3f(n - 3) + 4f(n - 4) if n >= 4
```

The iterative way to do this would be to start at the bottom until I hit `n`, so if n = 6:

```
f(4) = (3) + 2(2) + 3(1) + 4(0)     | 10
f(5) = f(4) + 2(3) + 3(2) + 4(1)    | 10  + 16 = 26
f(6) = f(5) + 2f(4) + 3(3) + 4(2)   | 26 + 2(10) + 17 = 63
```

Implementation attempt:

```
; m1...m4 | The results of the previous calculations (eg. f(n-1), f(n-2), etc.)
; result  | The result thus far
; counter | The current iteration of the loop--starts at 4 and ends at n
(define (fourf-iter n)
  (cond [(< n 4) n]
        [else
         (define (helper m1 m2 m3 m4 result counter)
           (cond [(= counter n) result]
                 [(helper result m1 m2 m3 (+ result m1 (* 2 m2) (* 3 m3) (* 4 m4)) (+ counter 1))]))
         (helper 3 2 1 0 10 4)]))
```

Several problems:

- The returned result is one iteration less than what it's supposed to be, because the actual calculations don't take place until the recursive call
- Instead of using the defined algorithm to calculate f(4), I'm just putting it right in there that `f(4) = 10`
- Ideally I want to start `result` at 0 and `counter` at 3 so that the calculations are applied to `m1` through `m4` (and so that `f(4)` will actually be calculated out instead of being preset), but then `0` gets used for m1 in the next iteration when it should be the result of `f(4)` instead (`10`)

tl;dr either the result calculation is delayed, or the result itself is delayed. How can I write this properly?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080321/why-am-i-getting-application-not-a-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the appropriately "Scheme-ish" way to write a function that's defined recursively like that is to use *memoization*. If a function `f` is *memoized*, then when you call `f(4)` first it looks up `4` in a key-value table and if it finds it, returns the stored value. Otherwise, it simply calculates normally and then stores whatever it calculates in the table. Therefore, `f` will *never evaluate the same computation twice*. This is similar to the pattern of making an array of size `n` and filling in values starting from 0, building up a solution for `n`. That method is called *dynamic programming*, and memoization and dynamic programming are really different ways of looking at the same optimization strategy - avoiding computing the same thing twice. Here's a simple Racket function `memo` that takes a function and returns a memoized version of it:

```
(define (memo f)
  (let ([table (make-hash)])
    (lambda args
      (hash-ref! table
                 args
                 (thunk (apply f args))))))
```

Now, we can write your function `f` recursively without having to worry about the performance problems of ever calculating the same result twice, thus going from an exponential time algorithm down to a linear one while keeping the implementation straightforward:

```
(define f
  (memo
    (lambda (n)
      (if (< n 4)
          n
          (+ (f (- n 1))
             (* 2 (f (- n 2)))
             (* 3 (f (- n 3)))
             (* 4 (f (- n 4))))))))
```

Note that as long as the function `f` exists, it will keep in memory a table containing the result of every time it's ever been called.

---

If you want a properly tail-recursive solution, your best approach is probably to use the *named let* construct. If you do `(let name ([id val] ...) body ...)` then calling `(name val ...)` anywhere in `body ...` will jump back to the beginning of the `let` with the new values `val ...` for the bindings. An example:

```
(define (display-n string n)
  (let loop ([i 0])
    (when (< i n)
        (display string)
        (loop (add1 i)))))
```

Using this makes a tail-recursive solution for your problem much less wordy than defining a helper function and calling it:

```
(define (f n)
  (if (< n 4)
      n
      (let loop ([a 3] [b 2] [c 1] [d 0] [i 4])
        (if (<= i n)
            (loop (fn+1 a b c d) a b c (add1 i))
            a))))

(define (fn+1 a b c d)
  (+ a (* 2 b) (* 3 c) (* 4 d)))
```

This version of the function keeps track of four values for `f`, then uses them to compute the next value and ditches the oldest value. This builds up a solution while only keeping four values in memory, and it doesn't keep a huge table stored between calls. The `fn+1` helper function is for combining the four previous results of the function into the next result, it's just there for readability. This might be a function to use if you want to optimize for memory usage. Using the memoized version has two advantages however:

1. The memoized version is much easier to understand, the recursive logic is preserved.
2. The memoized version stores results *between* calls, so if you call `f(10)` and then `f(4)`, the second call will only be a table lookup in constant time because calling `f(10)` stored all the results for calling `f` with `n` from 0 to 10.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, I'll keep that in mind, thanks. If I had to make f tail-recursive though, how would I go about it?